# How to identify SMT transitors

Tags: transistors, identification, surface-mount

im trying to identify the following 4 transistors, but am having trouble tracking them down.

The one that I think is the dual transistor is marked .1Ft on top of it, and the other three leg one is marked 3BW and then 2b (sideways on). After a search on the internet I found these two as possible replacements :
http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/271507549901?_trksid=p2059210.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT

http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/BC856B-NXP-Transistor-PNP-Sot-23-/360843952989?pt=UK_BOI_Electrical_Components_Supplies_ET&hash=item5403f9c35d

but info on these two transistors seems to be really thin on the ground. Is there a way to test the transistors and find out what the rated current etc is, as there are several of them on another board that I have that is identical and still working.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess we can actually identify those from the markings, as you can see [here for 1ft](http://www.s-manuals.com/smd/1f) and [here for 3bw](http://www.s-manuals.com/smd/3b). The 2b seems more tricky, but take a shot [here](http://www.s-manuals.com/smd/2b).

Answer (score 0):

Identifying SMD components is usually not possible. Markings, if present, rarely refer to what's inside the package. That is done because there is no room for useless information, and because printing them rises costs. Only "big" resistors, as 1206, are usually marked.

That said your best shot is to desolder one of the working one, find out if it's a fet or a bjt, then understand if it's a p or a n device testing it with very low voltages to avoid breaking it, then hope it's not some special very low noise, very high frequency, very whatever device, maybe having a guess at what it's doing on the board, buy a replacement and throw it in.

If there are several of them they are probably standard small signal transistors, some 100mA of collector/drain current, 100-ish hfe, 1-2V threshold voltage... But that's a wild guess.

Knowing what the board is supposed to do can help a lot.

Comment: Thanks for that, its a battery monitor board for an ebike, it also controls the balancing and charging in between cells.

Comment: with all that silicon I think it does something else too...

Comment: There are three pcbs in the photo for three separate packs, only the central pcb is fried.

Comment: Its this thing here, there are 7 connections for 7 packs http://adaptto.ru/i/BMS.jpg

Comment: Just thinking....would it be possible to work out a compatible component by hooking up some wires to some of the traces of the working ones and then measuring the current / voltages when it is turned on ?.

Comment: It might be possible but that's not something feasible, if you understand what I mean.

Comment: Why is it not feasible ?, as the other boards for the other cells still function as expected so I can monitor those ?. I do know that the power to the board is 13v and each cell is 4.2v

Comment: because we know nothing of the board so you can't be sure to explore the whole designed working space. i.e. you can measure 1mA of collector current but maybe sometimes for a reason that we can't know that current can spike to 100mA. you throw in a 10mA transistor and burn it. the time we are spending talking about it is probably worth more than the board itself, let alone the time spent measuring it.

Comment: Ah ok thanks, the board is sold for £100 so its not cheap